# How can I emulate css modules when using native browser ES modules?

Tags: javascript, css, es6-modules

I'm experimenting with building a site that leverages native browser support for ES6 JavaScript modules (not requiring build tools). Something I noticed early on is that unlike webpack the browser was not happy with a statement like `import "/myapp/style.css;"`.

Being able to associate CSS files with JavaScript-based components is really nice from a dependency tree maintenance perspective.

I'm wondering if there is a recommended approach to achieving this. Some ideas I've considered:

- Using something like JSS to move CSS into JS. Somewhat unappealing because you lose the IDE css syntax support and I assume that without a build process this is slower.
- Keeping CSS separate and using import statements within CSS to mirror JS dependencies. Unappealing to declare dependencies twice, and I don't think the browser will dedupe CSS imports like it does for modules.
- Establish a convention that Foo.js "auto-imports" Foo.css if available; write server-side logic that traverses the dependency tree and emits the relevant link tags. Seems like it will work, but requires more custom infrastructure (essentially what a build tool would do, but at runtime).

Is there a better way?

Comment: You're overthinking this. Use something like [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/) as a scaffolding/build tool and it will take care of this for you. Just make sure any CSS modules are written `[name].module.css`.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77075506/how-can-i-emulate-css-modules-when-using-native-browser-es-modules#comment135875864_77075506) @Andy: Maybe OP can provide clarity, but I interpret "_a site that leverages native browser support for ES6 JavaScript modules_" to mean "this project doesn't use build tools — I'm shipping raw source code".

Comment: Re: "_[CSS in JS is] unappealing because you lose the IDE css syntax support_": There are plenty of IDE extensions for supporting such nested syntax (example: [VS Code extension marketplace search results for `styled components`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=styled%20components&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance)).

Comment: @jsejcksn probably. Part of the problem is that CSS modules are not part of any standard (like ES modules) so implementation has to be done through a tool. You either define the tooling yourself, or use something like Vite which deals with CSS modules out of the box.

Comment: Appreciate the thoughts so far. I should have clarified that part of what intrigues me about the module approach is that it doesn't _require_ build tool support (I'll add that eventually but for curiosity's sake if for not other reason I want to see how far I can get without it).

Comment: It depends a bit on what you are using. If web components, you could get away with importing and adopting them in the shadow root. You could use a method to import, conver to `<style>` elements (or `link` if you dont want to do the import) and add them to the page itself. You will have to write a small utility method, and the path has to be either absolute or use `import.meta.url` to create a relative path. Luckily, modules allow wait so you could still import all of them at the top with `await`?

Comment: At the current time, there is no JavaScript runtime which implements a “CSS modules” API, so you’ll need to implement such a system yourself. Detailing such an implementation is far too complex to be [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for a single Stack Overlow Q/A, but you can start by learning about the [CSSOM APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model), generating deterministic hash strings, deduplication strategies, and researching existing tools’ “CSS modules” compiler implementations (e.g. esbuild, webpack, etc.).